# Why is Meteor not Executing Javascript on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

[Code](https://ide.c9.io/b2550/website-meteor)

I am having problems with meteor and on-page javascript.

I have a file called head which contains all the `<head>` code. Meteor merges this with the body when it is run. The problem I am having is that the code in the head is not working. I am referencing some javascript APIs that are then controlled by javascirpt in the head on the page. None of these scripts are activating and I believe that although these references are being loaded they are not being executed.

In meteor the only package I have that may be causing the problem is iron:router. I have tried to find other people with this problem but due to the lack of responses I believe it is a user error. If there is specific code you need feel free to ask and I will put it here.

*I apologize for the terrible colors of the site, that is being changed.*

Comment: Do you mind copying the relevant parts of the HTML and JavaScript here?

Comment: Your link forces us to login to the ide, so we can't even see your code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting any javascript directly inside the head like that. Instead, you should have no problem including the file like any other client-side JavaScript file. If you can post the relevant code, it should be pretty easy to show you how to include like this.

Comment: Sorry, I have not been near a computer. I will post code as soon as possible.

Comment: @sbking The problem is that when I tried that last without meteor it seemed not to execute but I will give it a try